# What is this theme called for atom?

Tags: user-interface, themes, atom-editor

Does anyone know what this topic is called for atom or specifically for sublime text?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please don't use images to provide textual information.

Answer (score 0):

Atom's default theme is called [Atom Dark UI](https://github.com/atom/atom-dark-ui)

However, the theme in your screenshot looks different. I suggest browsing [Atom Themes](https://atom.io/themes) to see if you can find it there.